# Getting data from ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rest-client, asp.net-webpages

I am working on Market and Financial News app.I took the API from `https://www.marketaux.com/`. I am trying to display the news from the site into my home page. I have created a model file and controller in ASP.NET Core web app file. In controller file, I get an error in `response.data` part as its showing response doesn't have data object whereas when I print the output of `response.Content`, it has data object. Can you tell me how to solve this and get access to the data from the API so that I can display it on my Home page?

Controller class:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Azure.Core;
using MarketNews.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySqlX.XDevAPI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;

namespace MarketNews.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NewsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public News[] GetNews() 
        {
            List<News> news = new List<News>();
            RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.marketaux.com/v1/news/all");
            // client.Timeout = -1;

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("News",Method.Get);
            request.AddQueryParameter("api_token", "qIWtsblpK93oeo23o87egUGBoVmVaqkl4fdHRTEc");
            request.AddQueryParameter("symbols", "aapl,amzn");
            request.AddQueryParameter("limit", "50");

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            if (response != null)
            {
                foreach (var article in response.data)
                {
                    news.Add(new News
                    {
                        Title = article.title,
                        Description = article.description,
                        Url = article.url,
                        Url_Image = article.image_url,
                        Published_At = article.published_at
                    });
                }
            }

            return news.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
namespace MarketNews.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Description;
        public string Url;
        public string Url_Image;
        public DateTime Published_At;
    }
}
```

I wanted to get data from the API and display it on my Home Page. I used `RestClient` and `RestRequest` to get response and then from response. I got the output when `response.Content` printed to console, it is working and it gave me a json file as output. In foreach loop when I tried to set the response data to the model data I created, it's showing `response.data` doesn't exist.

I want to know what is wrong here or is there any other method to get the data from the API?

Api: [Website link](https://www.marketaux.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RestSharp documentation](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference), the `Execute()` method does support for a generic type.

```cs
Execute<T>(IRestRequest request)
```

Note that, this method is deprecated. You shall look for the method below:

```cs
ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

and revamp your API action to support asynchronous operation.

From the response data shared in the link, you need a `Root` object which contains the `data` property with the `List<New>` type.

1. Define the data model class for the response.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("data")]
    public List<News> Data { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class News
{
    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("image_url")]
    public string Url_Image { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("published_at")]
    public DateTime Published_At { get; set; }
}
```

2. For the caller, specify the generic type as `Root`. Next extract the `data` property from the response with `response.Data.Data`.

```cs
RestResponse<Root> response = client.Execute<Root>(request);

// asynchronous way
// RestResponse<Root> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<Root>(request);

if (response != null)
    news = response.Data.Data;
```